# Using getClass.equals(otherObj.getClass()) in an implementation of equals(Object otherObj)

Tags: java, equals

A boilerplate implementation of an `equals(Object otherObj)` reads like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if(this == other)
            return true;
        if(other == null)
            return false;
        if(this.getClass() != other.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee e = (Employee) other;
        return (Objects.equals(this.name, e.name) && 
                Objects.equals(this.hireDay, e.hireDay) && 
                this.salary == e.salary);      
    }
```

Can we use:

```
if(!this.getClass().equals(other.getClass()))
```

instead?

Comment: more like `! this.getClass().equals(other.getClass())` (but equals is not needed here, despite not wrong either) - there is only one instance for each class (assuming same `ClassLoader`)

Answer (score 2):

`Class<T>` does not override `equals` and uses the default `Object#equals(Object)` implementation. Therefore, `a.getClass().equals(b.getClass())` is equivalent to `a.getClass() == b.getClass()`

`Object#equals(Object)` [is implemented as](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#L157):

> ```
> public boolean equals(Object obj) {
>     return (this == obj);
> }
> ```

Since your original condition is `this.getClass() != other.getClass()`, you have to write `!this.getClass().equals(other.getClass())`, if you were to translate it (but that should be very obvious)

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
a.getClass().equals(b.getClass())
```

is equivalent to

```
a.getClass() == b.getClass()
```

it can't instead the above equal method.